# Advantage or Disadvantage between Two Class Modules

Tags: vba

What would be the advantages or disadvantages of using Class1 instead of Class2?
The quantity information stored in each instance of the class will be adjusted up and down as needed (via the functions, and while it seems to make sense to me that I would only need to make these variables public so that they are visible from outside the class, I feel that there is most likely some reason that this shouldn't been done.

Class1

```
Option Explicit
Public Sequence As String
Public Quantity As Double


Public Sub AddQty(sAddQty As Double)
    Quantity = Quantity + AddQty
End Sub

Public Sub SubQty(sSubQty As Double)
    Quantity = Quantity - sSubQty
End Sub
```

Class2

```
Option Explicit
Private iSeq As String
Private iQty As Double

Public Property Get Qty() As Double
    Qty = iQty
End Property

Public Property Let Qty(lQty As Double)
    iQty = lQty
End Property

Public Property Get Sequence() As String
    Sequence = iSeq
End Property

Public Property Let Sequence(lSeq As String)
    iSeq = lSeq
End Property

Public Sub AddQty(sAddQty As Double)
    iQty = iQty + AddQty
End Sub

Public Sub SubQty(sSubQty As Double)
    iQty = iQty - sSubQty
End Sub
```

Comment: All depends on who will be using the objects, and how strict you want to be about encapsulation.  Functionally they're not really that different.

Comment: The excel add-in I'm working on will be using them to store the following info in a couple of  collections.  `All Parts In Production => Single Part = > All Steps Of Production For Part => Quantity Of Part At Given Sequence`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of interfaces, the two are exactly equivalent, because public fields are exposed as `Property` members. If you added a 3rd class module and wrote this:

```
Implements Class1
```

You would be forced by the compiler to add these members:

```
Private Property Get Class1_Sequence() As String
End Property

Private Property Let Class1_Sequence(ByVal RHS As String)
End Property

Private Property Get Class1_Quantity() As Double
End Property

Private Property Let Class1_Quantity(ByVal RHS As Double)
End Property

Private Sub Class1_AddQty(sAddQty As Double)
End Sub

Private Sub Class1_SubQty(sSubQty As Double)
End Sub
```

If you added another class module and wrote this:

```
Implements Class2
```

You would be forced by the compiler to have essentially the exact same members:

```
Private Property Get Class2_Sequence() As String
End Property

Private Property Let Class2_Sequence(ByVal RHS As String)
End Property

Private Property Get Class2_Qty() As Double
End Property

Private Property Let Class2_Qty(ByVal RHS As Double)
End Property

Private Sub Class2_AddQty(sAddQty As Double)
End Sub

Private Sub Class2_SubQty(sSubQty As Double)
End Sub
```

When properties do nothing and there's no incentive to properly encapsulate their values, go ahead and have public fields.

However there's little need for `AddQty` or `SubQty` instance methods when the backing field exposes a `Property Let` accessor - one could simply do `foo.Quantity = foo.Quantity + 2` instead. An API that appears to provide multiple ways to do the same thing, is a confusing API.

So what you do, is you define an explicit interface that defines the API you want to work with:

```
Public Property Get Quantity() As Double
End Property

Public Property Get Sequence() As String
End Property

Public Sub AddQty(ByVal value As Double)
End Sub

Public Sub SubQty(ByVal value As Double)
End Sub
```

And then make your class `Implements` this interface (say, `ISomething`), and the rest of the code works with this `ISomething` interface that only exposes the members you want it to be able to work with - and that excludes the class' `Property Let` members; the rest of the code only sees what it needs to see, and can only access what it needs to access.

```
Dim foo As ISomething
Set foo = New Something
'foo.Quantity = 42 ' illegal

Dim bar As Something
Set bar = foo
bar.Quantity = 42 ' ok
bar.AddQty 2
Debug.Print foo.Quantity ' should be 44
```

Comment: TY :) , I'm digging into class modules for the first time really and would rather not develop bad habits to have to break later.  This example helps to clear some things up